# Force Ember view refresh from bound helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, helper

I have a bound helper that looks like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('get', function(obj, options) {
     return obj.get(options.hash.prop);
});
```

I use it to display attributes while iterating over objects, e.g. *{{get obj propBinding="attr.name"}}*.
Since I don't know the attribute names beforehand, I can't use the dependency parameters (which, BTW, will throw an error in 1.0.rc4, even when used exactly as in the guide); so the view won't be refreshed when the attributes of *obj* change.

How would I force a view refresh when attributes displayed via the *get* helper change?